# draw a circle in three dimensional coordiantes

Tags: java, vector, geometry, minecraft

I want to draw a circle in three dimensional coordiantes, i'm given a vector, the angle where vector's intersects with the circle is 90 degrees, the intersection point is the centre of the circle. The radius can be parametrized. EDIT: I am programming a server plugin for minecraft. At this point I have made a sword that can be thrown. I want to add some decor. I want that after the sword there was a trace in the form of a circle. But I don't understand how to draw a circle in 3D coordinates so that the angle of intersection of the sword throw vector with the center of the circle is 90 degrees. The radius can be arbitrary, and the vector can enter the center of the circle. I thought I could just rotate the throw vector on 3 axes and get a circle, but nothing worked. I need an equation with which I can draw a given circle.

Comment: Please fix the "coordiantes".

Comment: Dupe: [circle in three dimensional coordiantes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562852/circle-in-three-dimensional-coordiantes)

Comment: You posted this exact same question yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have center `C`, normal vector `N`, radius `R`. Seems you want to get points at the circumference.

At first get some base vector in the circle plane.
Possible way:
Reveal normal component with the largest magnitude and with the second magnitude. For example, `abs(N.X)` is the largest, `abs(N.Z)` has the second magnitude, and `abs(N.Y)` is the smallest. Make the smallest component zero, exchange two larger ones, and negate the largest. For this example base vector will be:

```
A = (N.Z, 0, -N.X)
```

It is perpendicular to normal, hence lies in the circle plane.

Then get the next basis vector using [vector product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) (`B` will be perpendicular both to `A` and to `N`, it lies in the plane too)

```
B = N x A
```

Now normalize vectors `A` and `B` (make them unit length)

```
A = A / len(A)
B = B / len(B)
```

and you can get any point at the circumeference with parametric equation where `t` changes in the range `0..2*Pi`

```
P(t) = C + R * A * Cos(t) + R * B * Sin(t)
```

or in components:

```
P.X = C.X + R * A.X * Cos(t) + R * B.X * Sin(t)
and so on
```

Comment: Good technique to get the first orthogonal vector.